# Content preview unable to load

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Any idea why the preview doesn't work here??
When I use the Text field, the preview comes up with a following error:
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for update

==================================

|  MessageError: Connection interrupted

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var loginmode = false
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State var selectedTab = "Home"
@State var showMenu = false
  
    @State var visible = false
    @State var color = Color.black.opacity(0.7)
    var body: some View {
       
     
       
            TextField("Enter your email address", text: $userSettings.email)
                
        
      
    }
}
struct RegisterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Content of another file:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class UserSettings: ObservableObject
{
@Published var email = String()
}
```

The content of main file is as below:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct kokoburraApp: App {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(userSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: environment objects is required as you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Previews do not work without the necessary environment objects.

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
      .environmentObject(UserSettings())
  }
}
```